# How to Know the perfect photo size for ldpi hdpi... etc

Tags: android, image, screen, drawable, android-drawable

I want to support multiple screen that means I have to know the perfect image size for that screen

now I have 512px x 512px image
what should its size be in ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi?

and if anyone know any website that generates image sizes for me that would be a great help

Comment: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: @DerGolem isn't that for just icon launcher?